# Solr edge-ngram

Tags: search, solr, autocomplete, lucene

```
         <fieldType name="autocomplete_edge" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

This is what I am doing to get the auto-complete to work.It works with single word suggestion.When I type wh it gives me all questions starting with what is ******8
But it messes up when the query has a phrase like "what is"  and could not find results even though I have indexed many sentences starting with what is?
Any pointers

Comment: I think your problem with phrase queries is that you're using the keyword tokenizer. Try the standard tokenizer instead